# Online voice over lectures in powerpoint frustrations

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, editing

My issue is this.  While listening to PP and pause the audio to make my desire edits to the slide, I have to listen to the entire slide lecture again because the audio bar restarts.  Occasionally, the bar is extended as to were I ca slide my cursor over to where I approximately left off but other times, the bar doesn't have that capability.  Do you have any suggestions for students who just want to edit PP while listening to the audio.